# remove duplicate ip by notepad++

Tags: unique, duplicates

this is what i mean

i want this

```
200.22.30.17 : 186 : 186
200.22.30.17 : 1860 : 1860
200.22.30.17 : 1984 : 1984
81.22.148.39 : 1612 : 1612
81.22.148.39 : 1736 : 1736
81.22.148.39 : 1798 : 1798
81.22.148.39 : 186 : 186
81.22.148.39 : 1860 : 1860
81.22.148.39 : 1984 : 1984
20.47.240.254 : 2542 : 2542
20.47.240.254 : 2604 : 2604
```

to be like this

```
200.22.30.17 : 186 : 186
81.22.148.39 : 1612 : 1612
20.47.240.254 : 2542 : 2542
```

any help please !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Notepad++, but if it supports back-references then this ought to work:

Replace `^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+ )(.+)\n(\1.+\n)*` with `\1\2\n`

**Note:** Depending on how the line breaks are stored in your source file, you might have to change each occurrence of `\n` to `\r` or `\r\n`

Comment: Make sure the box which says ". matches newline" is unchecked. If you're working in Windows, you probably need to use `\r\n` instead of `\n` (in three locations).